# QGuiApplication pauses the event-loop when remote windows connection disconnected

Tags: qt, windows-10, remote-desktop

I am starting a QGuiApplication (Qt 5.12) and using a remote desktop connection to a Windows 10 PC. Everything works fine while the remote desktop connection is open, but when I disconnect and let the application run during the week-end, I can see in the logs that it stops processing Qt events (mostly network related in my case). The last thing the logs show is an "activation change" event.

When I connect again after the weekend, the Qt event loop starts again (the logs show again "Activation Change event") and of course there is a huge amount of queued events and the application gets in a non responding state (I am logging the number of Qt events queue in the loop using qGlobalPostedEventsCount).

This used to work correctly but stopped working, I think due to an update of Windows on the machine (maybe same root-cause than this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc03eb5c-2459-4d58-ac5a-3e288c40eda1/windows-10-remote-session-apps-pause-when-remote-desktop-disconnected?forum=winserverTS) ?).

Is this the expected behavior for applications when the windows remote connection is terminated? Is there a known fix for this?

Comment: It's very unlikely this problem is Qt-related. Did you try the fix as proposed in your linked MS forum thread?

Comment: @tofro I tried this fix, but then the application crashes inside atig6txx.dll. I think it is something similar to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61974 but I need to debug it further. I disagree that it is "very" unlikely to be Qt-related, since there are several similar issues in Qt forums.

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to properly fix the issue. As a work-around, using Microsoft "Remote Desktop" application instead of using the "Remote Desktop Connection" application avoids the issue.